# MS-Excel: Retrieve Row Number where VBA Function is located

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, row-number

I hope I'm asking this in the correct forum:

I'm writing a UDF in VBA for MS-Excel; it basically builds a status message for the transaction on that row. It steps through a series of IF statements, evaluating cell values in different columns FOR THAT ROW.

However, this UDF will reside in multiple rows. So it might be in C12, C13, C14, etc. How would the UDF know which row to use? I'm trying something like this, to no effect

```
Tmp_Row = Application.Evaluate("Row()")
```

which appears to return a null

What am I missing here ?

Thanking everyone in advance

Comment: `Application.ThisCell.Row`? Sounds like an XY problem though. Might be better to pass all relevant ranges to the UDF as argument(s).

Comment: Try Application.Caller.Row

Answer (score 1):

### Application.ThisCell

[`MS Docs:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thiscell)
*Returns the cell in which the user-defined function is being called from as a Range object.*

You can put it to the test using the following code:

```
Function testTC()
    testTC = Application.ThisCell.Row
End Function
```

In `Excel` use the formula

```
   =testTC()
```

and `(Cut)Copy/Paste` to various cells.

Comment: Again, not supposed to say thanks here, but thanks for the effort/solution.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Caller` is seldom used, but when a UDF needs to know who called it, it needs to know about `Application.Caller`.

Except, you cannot just assume that a function was invoked from a `Range`. So you should validate its type using the `TypeOf...Is` operator:

```
Dim CallingCell As Excel.Range
If TypeOf Application.Caller Is Excel.Range Then
    'Caller is a range, so this assignment is safe:
    Set CallingCell = Application.Caller
End If

If CallingCell Is Nothing Then
    'function wasn't called from a cell, now what?
Else
    'working row is CallingCell.Row
End If
```

Suggestion: make the function take its dependent cells as `Range` parameters (if you need the `Range` metadata; if you only need the values then take in `Double`, `Date`, `String` parameters instead) instead of making it fetch values from the sheet. This decouples the worksheet layout from the function's logic, which in turn makes it much more flexible and easier to work with - and won't need any tweaks if/when the worksheet layout changes.

Comment: So, not supposed to say "Thanks" here, but I don't know the correct spot.  So THANKS.  On a scale from 0 to 1 your suggestion = "1" Thanks